# Swift: JSON property conversion - varying JSON datatypes to the same Swift datatype

Tags: php, json, swift, swift3

I've come across an interesting issue when trying to use a JSON feed generated by PHP/MySQL using PDO. By default, the result of a query e.g. `SELECT COUNT(id) FROM table name` is returned as a `String`, but when I do any mathematical calculations on the result e.g. `$result = $result + 1;` the result is the 'correct' datatype.

In PHP, that's been no problem, but I'm using JSON to send these results to my iOS app, so although I know what datatype I want something to be in iOS, I don't know what type it's going to be when it reaches me. For example, I'd like to do:

```
if let json = jsonResult as? [String:Any] {
    let score = jsonData["score"] as? Int ?? 0
    let years = jsonData["years"] as? String
}
```

But:

1. If `score` is a `String` in the JSON (e.g. `score:"7"`), `score` will just end up as `0`
2. If `years` is an `Integer` in the JSON (e.g. `years:2015`), years will end up as `nil`

I realise that making the JSON correct is the best way to achieve this, however is there a reliable way to do this in iOS? For the sake of this question, assume that I cannot change the JSON.

I'm ideally looking for a sensible one-liner, that will allow me to convert to the correct datatype, regardless of what type it was previously (i.e. in the above example `years` will become a `String`, regardless of whether it was a `String` or `Int` in the JSON, and score will become an `Int` regardless of whether it was a `String` or an `Int` in the JSON)?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do somethink like

```
let score = Int(jsonData["score"] as? String)
```

Comment: What type is your json array in swift?

Comment: Just checking - that might well be it :)

Comment: i'm using that in my script and it works for me perfect :)